# Restored Wordpress Database Results in 500's

Tags: wordpress

I restored my wordpress MYSQL database and I had no idea what I was up for, this resulted in a my entire wordpress directory no longer displaying any pages (returning 404's or 500's)

When attempting to go to the installation directory through the browser the error log returns the follwoing error:

```
[10-Oct-2014 00:53:40] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  hash_equals() in /blog/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 674
```

This is what is on line 674

```
     if ( ! hash_equals( $hash, $hmac ) ) {
 675                 /**
 676                  * Fires if a bad authentication cookie hash is encountered.
 677                  *
 678                  * @since 2.7.0
 679                  *
 680                  * @param array $cookie_elements An array of data for the authentication cookie.
 681                  */
 682                 do_action( 'auth_cookie_bad_hash', $cookie_elements );
 683                 return false;
 684         }
```

I have removed all plugins out of my plugsins folder.  Tried to restore the database all with no luck.  I have tried to rename my default theme as well.

I also receive the same error when I go to login via wp_admin

Comment: try re-installing wp....also try without your default theme..if you haven't modified core files this is an unusual error...the only other reason i can think of is the paths are wrong for your installation.

Comment: I installed a fresh copy of WP in a new directory, then moved the wp-config.php to the new install and get the same result.  I think it is something related to the database restore.... take a look at www.thelocalgolfer.com/blog/

Comment: redo your config file and rename your htaccess file. if this works you'll need to go to settings + permalinks and save settings again. The database does not have any bearing on what functions are available to wp, it is most likely a path issue and wp cant find its files.  btw.. there is a blank screen on the link you gave me...

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions this is driving me nuts - I have renamed my htaccess file, now working on redoing my config and it still doesn't work.  I cannot even get the admin page to load it give me a blank screen - when i am authenticated this is the error that shows in the web console [code]The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer[/code]

Comment: ok check your database values for siteurl and home url. if these dont work you prob need to do a complete new install and import the tables you want (not the options table!)

Comment: Ok siteurl = http://www.thelocalgolfer.com/blog <- that appears correct, I don't see a home url field in the options table, is that something I need to create

Comment: Maybe you just meant the home value, home is also equal to http://www.thelocalgolfer.com/blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters above I did end up doing a fresh reinstall and then migrated the database over except for the options table.  Everything worked as good as new.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing some files? /wp-settings.php, /wp-includes/compat.php? If on a linux SO, does your web server user has read permissions?

Comment: No no files that I know are missing.  My linux webserver has read permissions set

Comment: The website provided gives me 200 status codes. Your 404 pages does trigger some text but there are some elements missing such as the CSS style sheet. It might just be a problem with your themes.

Comment: So I know this sounds odd, but I can't remember what theme name is active, is your suggestion to remove all themes in the themes folder, except the default?  Or grab the themes folder from a fresh install?

EDIT: ok found my active theme in the options table - it is neuro